# Always 'unresolved identifier' error when build IOS Framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I'm new to IOS Framework, I want to build a Framework for an app, so it can share the code with other apps. So I tried a single view app first. 
I built the cocoa touch framework project for one class, but when I used in another project, it always comes the "unresolved identifier" error.

Here is the simple class, I've add public key word.The name of the Framework is TipFrame.

```
import Foundation

public class TipCalculatorModel {

    public var total: Double
    public var taxPct: Double
    public var subtotal: Double {
        get {
            return total / (taxPct + 1)
        }
    }

    public init(total: Double, taxPct: Double) {
        self.total = total
        self.taxPct = taxPct
    }

    public func calcTipWithTipPct(tipPct: Double) -> (tipAmt:Double, total:Double) {
        let tipAmt = subtotal * tipPct
        let finalTotal = total + tipAmt
        return (tipAmt, finalTotal)
    }

    public func returnPossibleTips() -> [Int: (tipAmt:Double, total:Double)] {
        let possibleTipsInferred = [0.15, 0.18, 0.20]
        let possibleTipsExplicit:[Double] = [0.15, 0.18, 0.20]

        var retval = Dictionary<Int, (tipAmt:Double, total:Double)>()
        for possibleTip in possibleTipsInferred {
            let intPct = Int(possibleTip*100)
            retval[intPct] = calcTipWithTipPct(possibleTip)
        }
        return retval

    }
}
```

And here is how I used that

```
import UIKit
import TipFrame

class ViewController: UIKit.UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var totalTextField : UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var taxPctSlider : UISlider!
    @IBOutlet var taxPctLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var resultsTextView : UITextView?

    let tipCalc = TipCalculatorModel(total: 33.25, taxPct: 0.06)
```

For last line, it said: "**Use of unresolved identifier 'TipCalculatorModel'**

I used that to init a new object. And it came with "resolved identifier" error.
I wondered is that the error caused by architectures?

For the architecture, I build on the ios8.3, the valid architecture is arm64, armv7, armv7s.

**UPDATE**

I changed the setting of TipFrame, set "Build for active architecture only" to No. It works.

Comment: Is `TipFrame` the name of your framework? Can you copy/paste the exact error please?

Comment: TipFrame is my Framework, which I imported that in the ViewController file. thanks